# Crystal reports cross-tab month date function

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a cross-tab table that I want to group each column by an specific month for each year. (ex. March 2011, March 2012, March 2013 and so on).

I'm guessing that a formula is needed to do this since there's no predefined functions in CR that can help me group dates like that.

Is this true?

Comment: This is built into the group options: `This column will be printed: for each month`

Comment: Yes, but that function does not do what I want. As it says 'for each month' it shows **every** month for whatever time frame I input. Say, March-1-2011 to March-1-2015, it will group the columns by **every** month until March-1-2015. (March-2011, June-2011, July 2011.... and so on until March-1-2015)  What I want is just to show results for the month of March of each year.

Comment: you can build an store procedure to get that data from your tables and then create your crosstab based on the data returned by the SP or you may try using a formula a formula like if month(your date field) = 3 then "your date field" and format that formula to show only month and year and same for the columns if month(your date field) = 3 then "your field"